# How to do partial operations on python DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to subtract the mean of each column of my DataFrame for each part of it (ie for each index value "hostname"). I tried this :

```
for host in hostnames:
  df_temp = df.loc[host]
  df_temp = df_temp.subtract(df_temp.mean(axis=0))
  df.loc[host] = df_temp
```

... but it is taking forever (even for one loop).

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Found it : Didn't know about "level" parameter

```
df - df.mean(axis=0,level=0)
```

Comment: Hmmm, solution is working for you, but really hard answering with no data ;)

Comment: Sorry about that, I will try to ask better question next time

Comment: No problem, it is simple - sample data, expected output and what you try ;) Good luck!